# Working geofencing example broadcasting in background

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location, android-10.0, android-geofence

On Android 10 - I am looking for a way to do geofencing in background.

I need **geofencing broadcasts**, so that my app can react, even if it is not on the screen. 
For example by sending a notificaiton.

- I have tried the GeoFencing api: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing
- reporting to a frontend service
- reporting to a background service

When the app is on the screen - I get the notifications. 
When the app is NOT on the screen - nothing is triggered.
I am not sure, whether the broadcasts are not sent of if they are not passed to my receiver, or whether the receiver fails to call the app / send notifications.

Is there a working example for android 10?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 10 and above, to be able to use geofences in the background, you need to request and grant `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission first (along with `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and/or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`) before adding the geofence.

It is an added security precaution in Android 10, to prevent malicious applications from tracking your location while being in the background.

Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#background) for Android Documentation on accessing background location.

Comment: Hi @Skip Did my answer solve your issue? Please let me know if you are still facing an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. My app gets those permissions granted. I feel, like there are many factors I miss, hence I asked for an example

Comment: Can you please post your code so that I can help you identify the issue?